# Django rest framework - using SerializerMethodField with ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following models.

models.py

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Term(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    definition = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(default='', blank=True)
```

I want to write a Serializer that will return a list of subjects. Each subject has a term field, which contains None or a single object, depending on the `condition`.

serializers.py

```
class TermSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    language = serializers.CharField(source='language.name')

    def to_representation(self, data):
        data = data.get(language=self.context['language'])
        return super(TermSerializer, self).to_representation(data)

    class Meta:
        model = Term
        fields = ('id', 'language', 'name', 'definition', 'image')

class FilteredSubjectSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        if self.context['condition']:
            terms = Term.objects.filter(language=self.context['language'])
            data = data.filter(term__in=terms)
        return super(FilteredSubjectSerializer, self).to_representation(data)

class SubjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    term = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_term(self, term):
        if self.context['condition']:
            return TermSerializer(many=False, source='term_set').data
        return None

    class Meta:
        model = Term
        list_serializer_class = FilteredSubjectSerializer
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'definition', 'image', 'term')
```

The problem is that when `condition == True`, the ViewSet returns incorrect data. All fields inside term have a default value.

It works fine if I write `SubjectSerializer` like this:

```
class SubjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    term = serializers.TermSerializer(many=False, source='term_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Term
        list_serializer_class = FilteredSubjectSerializer
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'definition', 'image', 'term')
```

But the case when `condition == False` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the serializer the instance and the context.
Like this:

```
    def get_term(self, instance):
        if self.context['condition']:
            return TermSerializer(many=False, source='term_set', instance=instance, context=self.context).data
        return None
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked when I passed context and ```instance=instance.term_set```.